# Why I can't open font dialog again?

Tags: c#, dialog

I have font dialog and color dialog but when I use it once time then I cannot use it again.

Can you explain why and tell me how to fix it? Thanks

My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fontDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Color color = colorDialog1.Color;
                Brush brush = new SolidBrush(color);
                Convert_to_image(textBox1.Text, fontDialog1.Font, brush);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fontDialog1 = new FontDialog();

        if (fontDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
           //[..]
        }
    }
```

and to capture the colour for the font you could also try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fontDialog1 = new FontDialog() {ShowColor = true};

    if(fontDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //[..]
    }
}
```

Comment: When a form is opened with `ShowDialog` then the form isn't closed by the framework automatically. You can show a dialog mutliple times unless you `Dispose` or `Close` it (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: @Dirk - You looking at `ShowDialog` for the wrong control ie. `Form`, The `FontDialog` inherits from `CommonDialog` which is where `ShowDialog` comes from in this context... -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.fontdialog?view=netframework-4.7.2 In any case what you are suggesting is still right: `var fontDialog1 = new FontDialog(); if(fontDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) fontDialog1.ShowDialog();` will show the same dialog twice... So not sure why it did not work for @Jacob...

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware they used a different base class for those standard dialogs. Well, you always learn something here.

Comment: I wrongly assumed that was the reason `ShowDialog` did not behave as you'd expect... After your comment, I had to try though... And unsurprisingly you can call `ShowDialog` multiple times on the same instance as you can with `Form`